# Проверка содержимого поля формы на соответствие с элементами массив

Tags: angular

Необходимо проверять введенное в поле формы значение на соответствие существующему элементу из массива, который выводится в выпадающий список. Т.е. в поле должны вводиться только имеющиеся имена. Если в поле введено значение не из списка, то дизейблится кнопка отправки данных

```js
hasNameFound = false;
protected buildForm(): void {
    this.itemForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        nameValidation
    });
}

getListName(e): void {
    const {value} = e.target;
    if (value.length > 1) {
      this.itemService.getItems().subscribe(names => {
          this.hasNameFound = names.some(({name}) => name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
          this.namesFound = names;
        });
    }
  }
}

export function nameValidation(control: FormControl) {
  if (control.value && !this.hasNameFound) {
    return {
      'name': true
    };
  }
    return  null;
}
```

```html
<float-input [float]="!!itemForm.get('name').value">
        <input formControlName="name"
               [mdAutocomplete]="name"
               (input)="getListName($event)"/>
        <md-autocomplete #name="mdAutocomplete">
          <md-option *ngFor="let name of namesFound"
                     [value]="name">
            {{dispatcher.name}}
          </md-option>
        </md-autocomplete>
</float-input>

<button [disabled]="itemForm.invalid"></button>
```

Comment: почему ты не хочешь создавать воспроизводимые примеры на stackblitz или codesandbox?

Comment: @overthesanity, потому что в пример привожу лишь выдержку из кода, чтобы передать суть проблемы. может, кто-то явно видит в чем проблема

Comment: [а как насчет этого?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: воспроизводимый пример это обычное дело и ничего постыдного в этом нету  я, например, не до конца понимаю поставленную тобой задачу и не могу ничего сказать по куску шаблона который ты привел. С примером это было бы намного легче :)